# DB2 Control Center: Show SQL for Existing Table

Tags: sql, db2

I created a table visually in DB2 Control Center. Is there a way or command in DB2 to show the SQL source for the create-table, after it's created?

Answer (score 4):

There is a DB2-tool called db2look (command line) that can generate the DDL scripts for the creation of all the database objects (tables, views, constraints, ...). Have a look at the command options to let it create the DDLs of just 1 table and its constraints.

```
db2look -d YourDatabaseName -e -t YourTableName -o YourTableName.sql
```